# How to optimize nightly T-SQL procedure with a WHILE loop that updates a large number of rows?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a nightly procedure that updates tens of millions of rows which is taking around 40 minutes to run. I need to reduce the time it takes to execute. Here is a link to the execution plan: https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/?id=Sk5U7eqr2

- `T1` contains 755 rows
- `T2` contains 87,548,735 rows
- `T3` contains 87,447,307 rows

Code:

```
  

DECLARE @CT AS INT = 0;

  

SELECT     @CT = HB_FR_PERIOD     
 FROM    [Reset].[Hub_Fraud]   
WHERE DATEDIFF(DAY, HB_FR_CREATEDDATE, GETUTCDATE()) = 0



  WHILE (@CT < 2)


  BEGIN 
  
    UPDATE [SDP_Subscription].[dbo].[GEN_SUBSCRIBERS_HUB_FRAUD]
    SET 
     [HB_FD_UPDATEDDATE]   = CAST (  FORMAT (GETUTCDATE (), 'yyyy-MM-dd 00:00:00') AS DATETIME ), 
     [HB_FD_PR_Try_Flag]   = 0, 
     [HB_FD_PR_Try_Count]  = 0, 
     [HB_FD_PR_Try_Number]  = 0, 
     [HB_FD_PR_Billing_Flag]  = 0, 
     [HB_FD_PR_Billing_Count] = 0, 
     [HB_FD_PR_Billing_Number] = 0
    FROM
     [SDP_Subscription].[dbo].[GEN_SUBSCRIBERS_HUB_FRAUD] AS [TABLEA]
    INNER JOIN
     [SDP_Subscription].[dbo].[GEN_SUBSCRIBERS]    AS [TABLEB]
    ON 
     TABLEA.GEN_SB_ID_FK   = TABLEB.GEN_SB_ID
    WHERE
    (
     TABLEB.[GEN_SB_BILLING_SUCCESSDATE]         > TABLEB.[GEN_SB_INFO_PERIOD_DATE]
    AND 
     CONVERT(VARCHAR, GETUTCDATE()  - [TABLEB].[GEN_SB_INFO_PERIOD], 112) <= CONVERT(VARCHAR, TABLEB.[GEN_SB_BILLING_SUCCESSDATE], 112)  
    )
    OR 
    (
     [TABLEB].[GEN_SB_INFO_PERIOD] = 1
    )

;

    IF(@@ROWCOUNT >= 0)


     BEGIN
      UPDATE
       [Reset].[Hub_Fraud]
      SET
       HB_FR_PERIOD = HB_FR_PERIOD + 1
      WHERE
       DATEDIFF(DAY, HB_FR_CREATEDDATE, GETUTCDATE()) = 0


     END    
SET @CT = 0
SELECT 
    @CT = HB_FR_PERIOD       
FROM
    [Reset].[Hub_Fraud]    
WHERE
    DATEDIFF(DAY, HB_FR_CREATEDDATE, GETUTCDATE()) = 0
END
```

I've created indexes to narrow the scope of the scans required but that didn't reduce the execution time. I suspect the WHILE loop contributes to the procedures slow performance. Are there any anti-patterns in it or ways to optimize it?

EDIT: I've included the original code as requested. I've removed the transaction as that was added by my testing for rollback purposes. I didn't write this procedure, I was just tasked with speeding it up. I was told the loop is there for business purposes.

Comment: Making the `WHERE`s sargable would be the first thing. Why are you converting your date colum to a `varchar` in your first query? Syntax like `WHERE DATEDIFF(DAY, t3.col2, GETUTCDATE()) = 0;` isn't SARGable either. Why aren't you using date ranges?

Comment: you sure the script is correct? It looks like you create nested transaction inside the while loop but only commit once

Comment: IF(@@ROWCOUNT >= 0). uhh, that pretty much means if 1 = 1

Comment: It's really unclear what you are trying to do (because we can't see the names of anything), why do you need a `WHILE` at all, why not just do it all at once?

Comment: @ThomA I've removed all instances of non-sargable where's and removed the converts but the query still processes in the same time. Strangely, just removing the converts results in an additional 200k logical reads for the limited samples I'm using for testing.

Comment: Can you [edit] your question with the SARGable batch?

Comment: *"I was told the loop is there for business purposes."* That's a meaningless and, honestly, foolish reason. The "business" doesn't tell how the developers code, or what code methodology they use, the business defines *what* they business needs. Developers that let the business dictate *how* they code tend to be "yes people" that actually have no idea what they are and should be doing. If my manager told me to "use a loop, the business says so" I'd likely tell them how stupid an idea that is and reject said suggestion with a *much better* set based solution.

Comment: @ThomA So for the Sargable part I just removed all the non-sargables that you pointed out from the query to see if they were the cause of the slowdown. My limited sample set consisting of 1 million rows for each of the big tables still ran in the same amount of time with or without the non-sargables.

Comment: You just *removed* it? You didn't correct them?

Comment: Yes just to quickly see if they were responsible for the poor performance.

Regarding the loop, I'll bring it up with management again. If I'm not mistaken, simply running the first update followed by the second update without a loop would achieve the same result as the current loop, right?. I'll have to see if there's a business logic purpose for incrementing  HB_FR_PERIOD by + 1 or if it can be set to a fixed value right away.

Comment: But now you you'll be doing the operation again *every* row, so it'll be slower... Use a SARGable clause.

Comment: @ThomA I converted the outer queries and the smaller update's where clause to be sargable. They're now performing seeks, but performance is still the same unsurprisingly as the table they touch is small.

Is the larger update simply going to take a long time no matter what given that tens of millions of rows are being updated – at least as long as it's being performed in the loop.

Answer (score -1):

This might make the UPDATE run a bit faster:

```
UPDATE TABLEA
SET HB_FD_UPDATEDDATE = DATEADD(second, DATEDIFF(second, '2020', GETUTCDATE()), '2020')
    ,HB_FD_PR_Try_Flag = 0
    ,HB_FD_PR_Try_Count = 0
    ,HB_FD_PR_Try_Number = 0
    ,HB_FD_PR_Billing_Flag = 0
    ,HB_FD_PR_Billing_Count = 0
    ,HB_FD_PR_Billing_Number = 0
FROM SDP_Subscription.dbo.GEN_SUBSCRIBERS_HUB_FRAUD AS TABLEA
WHERE EXISTS
(
    SELECT 1
    FROM SDP_Subscription.dbo.GEN_SUBSCRIBERS AS TABLEB
    WHERE TABLEB.GEN_SB_ID = TABLEA.GEN_SB_ID_FK
    AND
    (
        TABLEB.GEN_SB_BILLING_SUCCESSDATE > TABLEB.GEN_SB_INFO_PERIOD_DAT
        AND
        DATEADD(day, DATEDIFF(day, 0, GETUTCDATE() - TABLEB.GEN_SB_INFO_PERIOD), 0)
            <= DATEADD(day, DATEDIFF(day, 0, TABLEB.GEN_SB_BILLING_SUCCESSDATE), 0)
        OR
        TABLEB.GEN_SB_INFO_PERIOD = 1
    )
);
```